# Unsatisfied dependency on javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: spring, maven, apache-servicemix

I have a maven + spring based application which I built and deployed in Servicemix.
However, when tried to start the bundle, it remained in the `Waiting` status for a long time before generating following exception:

```
16:25:52,219 | DEBUG | Timer-0          | DependencyServiceManager         | startup.DependencyServiceManager  339 | 72 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.0 | Deregistering service dependency dependencyDetector for OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle= abc, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml)
16:25:52,219 | ERROR | Timer-0          | WaiterApplicationContextExecutor | WaiterApplicationContextExecutor  432 | 72 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.0 | Unable to create application context for [abc], unsatisfied dependencies: Dependency on [(objectClass=javax.sql.DataSource)] (from bean [&dataSource])
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Application context initialization for 'com.vetstreet.pet_mailer' has timed out
```

Appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Did you configure the datasource for Servicemix?

Comment: right now all I have is the following line of code in my camel-context.xml file : <osgi:reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>. and to be more specific this application uses another application's datasource. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Extender holds back the startup of an application (setting it's status to *Waiting*) if a service that you're referencing is unavailable at startup. The reason is that the *availability* attribute of every referenced service is set to *mandatory*, and 
there's a *default-timeout* global attribute which is by default set to 5 seconds. If the service you're referring to doesn't appear in that amount of time, Spring Extender will throw an Exception like that you have. 
So what I think is something wrong with the service publication of your DataSource. Do you have the corresponding tag in your other application?

```
<osgi:service ...>
```

Check out this link: http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/service-registry.html. It contains a lot of example. Ensure that in both *osgi:service* and both *osgi:reference* you have the *javax.sql.DataSource* interface set. And be aware of not publishing the same interface by 2 different bundles.

One more thing: just to be sure, import the *javax.sql* package in your manifest:

```
<Import-Package>javax.sql</Import-Package>
```

Hope this helps, Gergely

Comment: On top of everything that Gergely said, you can use `osgi:ls` to figure out if there actually is a `javax.sql.DataSource` in OSGi Service Registry.  That way, you know whether you should be looking at a problem with the registration of the service or whether it is a duplicate class definition of this interface you're chasing down.

Comment: Thanks guys, the information was really helpful and I was able to resolve the issue with your suggestions. actually I had two bundles one with <osgi:service..> and other one without it. Apparantly the application which had <osgi:reference..> wasnt pointing to the correct one. Really great information. thanks a lot

Comment: Gertv, thanks for the info! I didn't know that 'ls' stands for listing the published services. Cool! :)